# How to create std::string from command line argument C++

Tags: c++, windows, string

**Important:** I am using Visual Studio C++ 2010 using C++03 and I cannot upgrade to C++11 with the Visual Studio because I am working on old Windows system. Also I am using UNICODE.

I am working on my own function to parse each argument of command line, but I cannot make it working because the types are different. First I tried to pass *a* to std::string constructor, then I tried to pass *b*.

```
MyClass::MyClass(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    _TCHAR *a;
    char b;
    std::string created;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        a = argv[i];
        b = *argv[i];
        std::string created(a); 
        std::istringstream ss(created);
        std::string token;

        while(std::getline(ss, token, '-')) 
        {
            std::cout << token << '\n';
        }
    }
};
```

Error

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_TCHAR *' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &' ...
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a main() method? Just to ask

Comment: I am creating my own method because I have my specific needs for parsing each of the argument. I dont want to parse it with standard C method.

Comment: @user3740121 Sounds like you'll need to use [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with your actual environment.

Answer (score 1):

As Marco A. said, that's not unicode. And as πάντα-ῥεῖ said, You need to use std::wstring.

If you wish both char and wchar versions, you can use something like:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef std::string tstring;
#else
    typedef std::wstring tstring;
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem. The problem was in the main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

I used int main(int argc, char* argv[]) instead.

Now it works:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *a;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        a = argv[i];
        std::string created(a); 
        std::istringstream ss(created);
        std::string token;

        while(std::getline(ss, token, '-')) 
        {
            std::cout << token << '\n';
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not unicode. I believe you have no clue on what's going on and I suggest reading something about unicode and MSVC project settings